# Button doesn´t remember shape

Tags: android, button, colors, shapes

I created a circular-shaped (small) Button which changes  it´s color onClick.
When the button is clicked the Color goes from red-pink Gradient color to red.

My problem is, that the button doesn´t stay round when the color changes.

It would be awesome if someone could help me. :)

That´s the XML-file for the shape and color of the button, created in drawable-folder, Name = ne.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
    <gradient android:startColor="#FFFF0000" android:endColor="#80FF00FF"
        android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

That´s my code:

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Button b;


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                b.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF4444"));

        }
    });
}
}
```

Thank´s in advance,

-AD :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use shapes combined with [selectors](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/Selector.html) for your task. A selector is basically a list of shapes that the button should take basen on its enabled, clicked and focused state.

Selectors are usually defined in XMLs, again in the `drawable` folder of your resources. See [this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/) example.

What you are doing is mimicing the selector functionality, but is far less clear and harder to maintain (not to mention the reusability).

**EDIT** And to answer your question as of why you get this behavior, take a look at the implementation of [`setBackroundColor`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/view/View.java#View.setBackgroundColor%28int%29), for a `View` - it resets the background shape, replacing your initial shape.

Comment: Hi Boris, it doesn´t work 100% fine. The Problem is, that the button doesn´t stay in the new Color. I did exactly what the tutorial told me but the button only changes it´s Color when it´s pressed.

Comment: @ANDROID_DEV Please be more explicit on what you did. You basically need to define two shapes - one with the default color and one with the pressed color. Use the second one in the pressed state of the selector

Comment: @ANDROID_DEV Now actually as I come to think of it selector might not be the thing you actually need - I think you need to keep the new color. However, android has also the changing states drawable: transition drawable. Link to tutorial: http://kirill-poletaev.blogspot.com/2013/02/android-beginner-tutorial-part-88.html

Comment: @ANDROID_DEV I am glad that I helped. Please remember about both transition drawables and selectors and use them when appropriate.

Comment: Oh one last Thing, can I disable the fuction, that the object Color chnages when it tap the Screen anywhere? Because at the Moment the object´s Color changes also when I tap nexto it.